Formalizing the boundary function $\partial_n$ and proving $\partial_n\partial_{n+1}=0$
I'm trying to formalize homologies in Mizar, following Allen Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.

I start by defining a Simplex as a one-to-one tuple $(v_0,\cdots,v_n)$ of a real vector space that has affinely-independent range (one-to-one is needed because the affinely-independent property is defined on sets, not tuples, in Mizar, see RLAFFIN1). When $s$ is a Simplex, I define $\Delta s$ as its convex hull. This way I keep the simplexes oriented.
$\operatorname{canSimplex}(n)$ is defined as a Simplex of unit vectors $(e_0, \cdots, e_n)$ in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ and with this notation $\Delta\operatorname{canSimplex}(n)$ is the $\Delta^n$ from AH.
Let $X$ be a TopSpace (cf. PRE_TOPC), then a SingularSimplex of n, X $\sigma$ is a continuous Function $\sigma:\Delta^n\rightarrow X$. SingularSimplexes(n,X) is the set of all possible $\sigma$.
Now the "formal sum" makes formalization a little bit sophisticated: I define SingularChains(n,X) to be sum(SingularSimplexes(n,X) --> INT.Group) (cf. GROUP_7). So a formal sum $\sum_i n_i\sigma_i$ is formalized as a function from all possible $\sigma$ to $\mathbb Z$ (with finite support).
insert_0_at(n,i) is the $d_i:\Delta^n\rightarrow\Delta^{n+1}$ from this answer.

Now comes the part I am unsure about. To grasp $\sigma|[v_0,\cdots,\hat v_i,\cdots,v_n]$ I define for an $(n+1)$-chain $C$ and a singular $n$-simplex $S$ the set support(C,S,i) as the set of all singular $(n+1)$-simplexes $S'$ with $C(S')\neq 0$ and $S=S'\circ d_i$.
Then I can define $\sigma|[v_0,\cdots,\hat v_i,\cdots,v_n] = \sigma \circ d_i$ as the function Boundary(C,i) which maps any singular $n$-simplex $S$ to Sum(C*canFS support(C,S,i)) ($C=\sigma$), right? canFS is just a mechanism to sum up all the $C(S')$.

The last step is summing up all the Boundary(C,i) with the correct sign to Boundary(n,X) or $\partial_n$. That was easy again.

I want to know if this formalization is correct so far? One way to assure me is proving that $\partial_n\partial_{n+1}=0$ in the formalization system. This appears somewhat tricky though, because I cannot switch around summation indices as easily as one does in regular math.

Why the downvote?

I did not downvote, but this does not seem to be a math question, it is a programming question: you are asking people to check your code. Do you have math questions about homology theory?

This is formalization of homologies. I get it's niche, but it's a math question nonetheless. This is about understanding the definition of $\sigma|[v_0,\cdots,\hat v_i,\cdots,v_n]$. The "code" is just one way to write math down.

Then you should state the question clearly. Hat means that you skip the vertex $v_i$ amd considerthe face defined by the rest of the vertices: this can be found literally in every algebraic topology textbook.
